# Find at least one word of even length accepted by finite automaton

Tags: prolog

I Have an automaton. 
The question here is: how to find at least one word of even length accepted by my given finite automaton?

```
states      /* states(Q) <=> Q is the list of automata's states */
symbols     /* symbols(Sigma) <=> Sigma is the list of automata's input symbols */
transition  /* transition(X, A, Y) <=> δ(X, A)=Y */
startState  /* startState(S) <=> S is the start state of automata */
finalStates /* finalStates(F) <=> F is the list of automata's final states */


states([q0, q1, q2]).
symbols([a, b]).
transition(q0, a, q1).
transition(q0, b, q2).
transition(q1, a, q2).
transition(q1, b, q0).
transition(q2, a, q1).
transition(q2, b, q2).
startState(q0).
finalStates([q2]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have successfully encoded your automaton in Prolog. What you are actually missing is the code to execute it. So let's think about what's needed to do that. First, we need to kick off the execution by passing the input to something to run it. That first thing will find the start state and use that. Then we'll run a loop, finding the transition for this state and the next input value and next state. If we run out of input and are in a final state, then we have succeeded. So it seems like the only thing special about the first call is that it looks up the initial state.

In true inductive fashion, let's write the termination condition first.

```
step(State, []) :- finalStates(FinalStates), memberchk(State, FinalStates).
```

This simply says that if we try to perform a step when we're out of input, the state we were in is in the list of final states. Now let's try to run a step that is not the final step. We'll recursively call `step/2` to implement a loop.

```
step(State, [Sym|Tape]) :-
    transition(State, Sym, NextState),
    step(NextState, Tape), 
    !.
```

This simply peels off the next symbol on the tape and finds the right next state based on it, and recurs. I have added the cut here to prevent it from attempting to find other transitions; if you were building an NFA you might want to remove that. Now what we are missing is the initial driver, which I'll just call evaluate:

```
evaluate(Tape) :-
    startState(Start),
    step(Start, Tape).
```

Let's try this out on a few inputs:

```
?- evaluate([a,a,a,a]).
true.
```

This succeeded because it transitioned from q0 -> q1 -> q2 -> q1 -> q2 and q2 is a final state.

```
?- evaluate([a,a,a]).
false.
```

This failed because it transitioned from q0 -> q1 -> q2 -> q1 and q1 is not a final state.

Now on to finding strings that match. We can generate them quite easily since we have the set of symbols on-hand; let's make a little helper predicate:

```
symbol(X) :- symbols(Symbols), member(X, Symbols).
```

This is something we can use easily with `maplist/2` to generate sample inputs:

```
?- length(L, 3), maplist(symbol, L).
L = [a, a, a] ;
L = [a, a, b] ;
L = [a, b, a] ;
L = [a, b, b] ;
L = [b, a, a] ;
L = [b, a, b] ;
L = [b, b, a] ;
L = [b, b, b].
```

Now you can do a classic generate-and-test thing with Prolog:

```
?- length(L, 3), maplist(symbol, L), evaluate(L).
L = [a, a, b] ;
L = [a, b, b] ;
L = [b, a, a] ;
L = [b, b, b].
```

To find an even list of symbols that works, make a helper for finding evens and we'll use `between/3` to generate lists of those lengths and then do the same kind of thing:

```
even(X) :- 0 is X mod 2.
```

Trying:

```
?- between(1,100,X), even(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 8 .

?- between(1,100,X), even(X), length(L, X).
X = 2,
L = [_2954, _2960] ;
X = 4,
L = [_2954, _2960, _2966, _2972] ;
X = 6,
L = [_2954, _2960, _2966, _2972, _2978, _2984] .

?- between(1,100,X), even(X), length(L, X), maplist(symbol, L).
X = 2,
L = [a, a] ;
X = 2,
L = [a, b] ;
X = 2,
L = [b, a] ;
X = 2,
L = [b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, a, a, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, a, a, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, a, b, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, a, b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, b, a, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, b, b, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, b, b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [b, a, a, a] .

?- between(1,100,X), even(X), length(L, X), maplist(symbol, L), evaluate(L).
X = 2,
L = [a, a] ;
X = 2,
L = [b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, a, a, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, a, b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, b, a, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [a, b, b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [b, a, a, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [b, a, b, b] ;
X = 4,
L = [b, b, a, a] ;
X = 4,
L = [b, b, b, b] ;
X = 6,
L = [a, a, a, a, a, a]
```

Comment: I try to this one and I have false. 
?- evaluate([a,a,a,a]).


I understand everything you wrote, but it is not working. And my task was different. I need to check does the automat allow at least one word that has ever length or can multiple of 3.
Maybe, I need something like that
`multiple(L):- L mod 3=0`
L - length

Comment: @NastassiaBu I have edited the answer to show how you use it to find solutions. I don't know why it isn't working for you, perhaps you need to make a new console and paste in the code again?

Comment: It is ok. Thank you!)